# Issues installing quickfix library for Windows on Python2.6

Tags: python, quickfix

Couldn’t find a compiled quickfix library for Python2.6 on Internet.
That’s why the running of build was necessary.
I downloaded package quickfix-1.15.1 from https://pypi.org/project/quickfix/ which contains setup.py
And started building with command:
`C:\Python26\python.exe setup.py build`
The process interrupted after some error messages about missing include file tr1/memory and wrong compiler option /Wno-deprecated.
I use Visual Studio 2019 compiler.
Seek an advice on how to get on.

Comment: Please post the exact error message , if you still want help.

Comment: I have found a workaround for this problem in the meantime. Thanks.